# facing problems with terms filter

Tags: elasticsearch

My mapping looks like the below.
"BID": {
    "type": "string"
},
"REGION": {
    "type": "string"
},

Now I am trying to search for the records whose BID values are B100, B302. I've written below query. Though I've records with those ID values, I am not getting any results. Any clue where I am doing wrong?

{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"terms": {"BID": ["B100","B302"]}}}}}

Comment: have you set the field mapping to "not_analyzed"? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lower-case values, like:

```
{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"terms": {"BID": ["b100","b302"]}}}}}
```

You need to do this because, since you did not specify an analyzer in the definition of `"BID"` in your mapping, the default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is used, which will convert letters to lower-case.

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the case in your index terms, you can add `"index": "not_analyzed"` to your mapping definition for `"BID"`.

To test I set up an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "BID": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "REGION": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

added a few docs:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"REGION":"NA","BID":"B100"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"REGION":"NA","BID":"B200"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"REGION":"NA","BID":"B302"}
```

and now your query works as written:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "BID": [
                  "B100",
                  "B302"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "REGION": "NA",
               "BID": "B100"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "REGION": "NA",
               "BID": "B302"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/b4b4767501df7ad8b6459c4d96809d737a8811ec

Comment: Thank you. Lowercase worked. When I've added index:"not_analyzed" for BID, my original query is still not working.

Comment: Did you reindex the data?

Comment: yes. I did. But still facing the problem with upper case.

Comment: There must be something else going on, then. That's the best I can do with what you posted in the question. Maybe if you posted your entire mapping, some sample data, and the full query you are using it would help to track down the problem you're having.

Comment: Now its working. I've restarted elastic server and re-indexed the data. Then it started working.Thank you